# Como hacer un árbol de procesos con fork en C

Tags: c, bucle-for, árboles-binarios, proceso

Estoy tomando la materia de sistemas operativos y tengo de ejercicio realizar el siguiente árbol de procesos en C con fork();, el programa debe recibir 2 argumentos la altura y el ancho ( de 3 y 2 respectivamente) y crear el árbol de esta imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se tiene que realizar el código a partir del siguiente esqueleto:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 int i, height, width;
 if (argc!= 3) exit(0);
 height = atoi(argv[1]); /* height */
 width = atoi(argv[2]); /* width */
 /* tu codigo aqui */
 printf("Soc el process %d y meu pare es %d\n", getpid(), 
getppid());
 sleep(1);
 return 0;
}
```

He realizado varios códigos pero no encuentro la solución, lo mas cercano que me he quedado es:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int
main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{  
int i,x, height, width;  
pid_t pid,pid2; 
if (argc != 3)
    exit (0);  
height = atoi (argv[1]);    /* height */
width = atoi (argv[2]); /* width */  
    /* tu codigo aqui */ 
for (i = 1; i < height; i++)    
{
    pid=fork();
    if(pid<0){pid2 = fork();}
} 
printf ("Soy el proceso %d y mi padre es %d\n", getpid (), getppid ());  
sleep (1);
return 0;

}
```

Pero lo único que le falta es crear del primer proceso dos procesos hijos, es decir el hijo 2 del diagrama no es creado.

Trate de crear también un código que crea una cadena de procesos uno después de otro y otro que crea dos procesos de un padre, pero no estoy seguro como unir los códigos para crear este árbol.
¿Alguien me podría ayudar?

Este es el código de la cadena que realice:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 int i, height, width;
 pid_t pid,pid2;
 if (argc!= 3) exit(0);
 height = atoi(argv[1]); /* height */
 width = atoi(argv[2]);
    for (int i=0; i<height; i++)     
    {
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == -1) { /* handle error*/ }
        else if (pid == 0) {
            printf("Soc el process %d y meu pare es %d\n", getpid(),getppid());
        }
        else { // parent process
            wait(NULL);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
  printf("Soc el process %d y meu pare es %d\n", getpid(),getppid());
}
```

El código que hice que crea dos hijos de un padre es este:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 int i, height, width;
 pid_t pid,pid2;
 if (argc!= 3) exit(0);
 height = atoi(argv[1]); /* height */
 width = atoi(argv[2]); /* width */
 /* tu codigo aqui */
 for(int i=0;i<width;i++) // loop will run n times (n=5)
    {
        if(fork() == 0)
        {
            printf("[son] pid %d from [parent] pid %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
            exit(0);
        
        }
    }
  printf("Soc el process %d y meu pare es %d\n", getpid(),getppid());
  for(int i=0;i<height;i++) // loop will run n times (n=5)
  wait(NULL);
}
```

Quería saber si es mejor idea unir dos códigos como estos o modificar el primero y como hacerlo :C

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo en el código que muestras parece que no acabas de dominar qué código ejecuta el padre y qué código ejecuta cada hijo. Para no resolverte el problema directamente te dejo un código de muestra en el que un mismo padre genera 3 hijos.

Recuerda que en el momento que se ejecuta un fork() las siguientes líneas de código son ejecutadas tanto por el padre como por el hijo que creó dicho fork.Así que para controlar el código que quieres que ejecute cada uno, debes añadir algún tipo de control aprovechándote de comprarar con los PID.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
  
//En este ejemplo se generan 3 hijos del mismo proceso padre.
int main()
{
    int pid, pid1, pid2;
  
    
    // La variable pid almacena el valor devuelto del fork() system call
    pid = fork();
  
    // Si fork() devuelve 0 indica que es un hijo (el primero)
    if (pid == 0) {
        //Este código sólo lo ejecutará el hijo1
        printf("child[1] --> pid = %d and ppid = %d\n",
               getpid(), getppid());
    }
  
    else {
        //La siguiente instrucción sólo la ejecuta el padre
        pid1 = fork();
        //Aquí va el segundo hijo.
        if (pid1 == 0) {
            printf("child[2] --> pid = %d and ppid = %d\n",
                   getpid(), getppid());
        }
        else {
            pid2 = fork();
            if (pid2 == 0) {
                //Este es el tercer hijo.
                printf("child[3] --> pid = %d and ppid = %d\n",
                       getpid(), getppid());
            }
  
            //Si el valor retornado por el fork() no es 0 y es >0
            else {
                //Este código sólo lo ejecutará el Padre
                printf("parent --> pid = %d\n", getpid());
            }
        }
    }
  
    return 0;
}
```